# Convert fillable PDF to fillable html form

Tags: itext, acrobat

I want to convert a fillable pdf form to a fillable html form. I had tried conversion using iTextSharp but it couldn't convert to fillable html form.

Answer (score 3):

PDF forms and HTML forms are fundamentally different from each other, so that it would be an extremely difficult task to do a conversion.

You'd be better off and faster by simply recreating the form in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple PDF to HTML converters that can convert PDF Form to HTML Form. Here are some I'm aware of

[PDF Form Viewer](http://pdfformviewer.com/) - based on JavaScript

[PDF Forms to HTML Forms](https://pdfix.net/features/formfilling/) - cross-platform SDK & CLI

[PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) - desktop or server Windows only